# Flutter - textField doesn't scroll to caret position on value change

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I try to build a custom keyboard, but I have a problem with `TextField` doesn't scroll to position of caret when there are more characters than width of `TextField`. I have set keyboardType to none. When I use virtual keyboard, everything works. Is there any way to do it?

**How it works with virtual keyboard, I want to achieve this effect**

[image: g]

**How it works with the textButton which add number**

[image: g2]

```dart
   final textFieldController = TextEditingController();

  TextField(
    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
    autofocus: true,
    cursorHeight: 50,
    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
    controller: textFieldController,
  )

   // this function is executed when the button is clicked
   void textFieldChange(String value) {
     var selectionObj = textFieldController.selection;
     var textFirstPart, textSecondPart, caretPos= selectionObj.baseOffset;

     if (caretPos &lt; 0) {
       caretPos = textFieldController.text.length;
     }
     textFirstPart = inputValue.substring(0, caretPos);
     textSecondPart = inputValue.substring(caretPos);

     setState(() {
       inputValue = textFirstPart + value + textSecondPart;
     });
     textFieldController.text = inputValue;
     textFieldController.selection = 
     TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: caretPos + 1));
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I think I got it. I had to use `scrollController`.

```dart
String inputValue = '';
final textFieldController = TextEditingController();
final scrollController = ScrollController();
final _textFieldKey = GlobalKey();

void followCaret() {
    TextPainter painter = TextPainter(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
      text: TextSpan(
        text: inputValue,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
      ),
    );
    painter.layout();

    const double caretWidth = 2;

    TextPosition cursorTextPosition = textFieldController.selection.base;
    Rect caretPrototype = const Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, caretWidth, 50);
    Offset caretOffset =
        painter.getOffsetForCaret(cursorTextPosition, caretPrototype);

    final width = _textFieldKey.currentContext?.size?.width as num;
    final clientX = caretOffset.dx - scrollController.offset;
    final diff = width - clientX;

    if (caretOffset.dx > width &&
        cursorTextPosition.offset == inputValue.length) {
      scrollController.jumpTo(caretOffset.dx - width + caretWidth);
    } else if (diff < 0) {
      scrollController
          .jumpTo(caretOffset.dx - clientX + diff.abs() + caretWidth);
    }
  }

void textFieldChange(String value) {
     ...
     TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: caretPos + 1));
     followCaret();
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code snippet?

Comment: Code snippet included.